# Image zooming transition from UITableViewCell to UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, core-animation, uiviewanimationtransition

I'm trying to implement an animation for the custom transition (iOS7, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning), when a thumbnail image from a UITableViewCell starts zooming out to fullscreen and the transition ends up with a new (modal) UIViewController fullscreen with a background image, which is a higher quality of the image in the thumbnail of the source UITableViewCell.

The "preparation" code to use the custom transition is fine and now I'm struggling with an actual animation implementation inside of the delegate's method:

```c
- (void)animateTransition:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    UIViewController *fromVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController *toVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];

    CGRect sourceRect = [transitionContext initialFrameForViewController:fromVC];
    CGRect finalRect = [transitionContext finalFrameForViewController:toVC];

    UIView *container = [transitionContext containerView];

    if (self.mode == TRANSITION_MODE_INITIAL) {
       //TODO: back to the table listing

    } else if (self.mode == TRANSITION_MODE_MODAL) {
       //TODO: take a thumbnail and zoom out, then replace with toVC's view?
    }
}
```

I'm passing to this custom Transition class the selected UITableViewCell, therefore I have access to all the subviews of the cell to implement the animation.

The points I can't get properly:

1. Would it be correct just to zoom in the toVC and place it on the thumbnail position (frame) and then animate its zoom-out instead of scaling the actual thumbnail?
2. What's the role of the container here? How to use it properly?